# Setting the client name for an Authorized API client in Google

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-apps-for-education

I have developed a few small apps that connect to our google domain.  However each time I have to authorize one of these apps I need to add a different 
Authorized API client by using it's "Client Name".  Is there a way to set this client name to something of my choosing?  It would make it much easier to quickly understand what apps are OK to remove from the list later on.

Thanks!

...edit...

I may not have been specific enough, here is an image of where I want to change the value.  This is from the google admin console for google apps under Security -> Show More -> Advanced Settings -> Manage API Client Access

[CLient Name Field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13qSK.png)

For all the apps I've developed so far my Client Name(which I pull from the google developers console) is either a seemingly random string of only numbers or a random string of numbers and letters follow by "apps.googleusercontent.com".  Yet I've seen other apps that somehow have their company name listed there.  How can I choose my own Client Name as I've seen in other apps?

Comment: Did you figure it out? I've always wonder the same thing. I want to see my custom name in the 'Manage API Client Access' list, instead of the actual Client ID number.

Answer (score 0):

You can set client name and the scope by goinog on the `Manage client API` access page. Register your client in the `Authorize a new API client` settings.

Enter the client name provided by the third-party vendor and specify the scope. Add a new client by entering the client name (OAuth consumer key) and API scope and clicking "Authorize". You should verify that the client is known to you and that they have an appropriately small scope of access.

For each client, you can specify multiple APIs, separated by commas. For example, to allow access to both the Contacts and Documents List APIs: `"http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/`, `http://www.google.com/feeds/"`. The list of clients is unique, and cannot have two entries in the list for one OAuth client. You can use any of the Google APIs that currently support [two-legged OAuth for Google Apps domains](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes].)

*Authorized API Clients*

Add your APIs from the list of approved clients and their scope.

After the client has been added, you can remove a client that has a specified API scope by clicking the "Remove" link. If the client is the OAuth consumer key for your Google Apps domain, you'll see the link, "Manage". Clicking this link takes you to the Manage OAuth key and secret for this domain page where you can edit the client (for example, turn off global API scope access).

For more information about OAuth, please follow this link: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority

Comment: I am the Third party vendor, AND the admin of the google apps domain.  The problem is I don't like the Client Name that google provided to my app by default as it's hard to sort through when you have a bunch of custom developed apps listed all with random strings of characters instead of easy to read names.

Answer (score 0):

In case you meant how to set the application name when you connect with the php api client, you can use:

```
$client->setApplicationName('App Name Here');
```

Comment: This seems to only change it within the instance of the running app.  Not within the google admin console which is what I am looking for